# International Search Engines

Tags: seo, international

Forgive me for using this forum improperly if I am, but I love this site so much, I wanted to start here.

I recently took a position that's going to have me working with international search engines, most notably Baidu in China.

Does anyone have some tips or places to start looking on SEO techniques?  Does their indexing/robots work along the same lines as Google/Bing/Yahoo! etc?

Does anyone have experience with this?

Again, I apologize if this is not the proper place, but there are a healthy amount of people in the same industry in this community so I wanted to try.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, optimization is the same for all of the search engines. One way or another it all boils down to usability, accessibility, semantic markup, and quality content. So if your site is built properly it *should* be optimized for every search engine.

Having said that, it is very obvious that the algorithms for each search engine vary as they all return different results for the same query. Google's algorithm is the most widely discussed, thanks to it's dominance in search, and most advanced. This means most of the SEO articles you will read will specifically mention Google. But most of what you read will also apply to the other search engines like Bing and Baidu.